# Receiving the below mentioned error in JMeter while using Delete Request. Unable to find why this error occurred

Tags: api, testing, jmeter, request, http-delete

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **/var/www/maps/api/place/DeletePlace.php** on line **42**

Comment: Need more details. Perhaps a screenshot highlighting error and masking confidential details.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the application you're testing tries to [read some property from something not being an object](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350557/what-does-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-mean).

1. If the behaviour can be reproduced using a real browser it indicates a bug in your application
2. If it happens only with JMeter and isn't reproducible with the browser you need to cross check the request JMeter sends using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and the request the browser sends using "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) - the requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

The most common mistake when it comes to API testing using JMeter is that people forget to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and configure it to send a valid [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header